BizTalk Health Monitor V5 crashes when creating custom rules
I'm trying to create a new custom rule in BHM V5.0.9118. I open the "Profile settings" window then go to "Rules" tab then check "List custom rule only" and then click "New rule" and the BHM window just disappears without any warning.
Do I miss something about the creation of a custom rule? Or maybe I miss a configuration or a settings?
BizTalk server version: BizTalk 2020 3.13.717.0 (CU5)

It does look like a bug.
But if you don't click List custom rules only, you get the "New Rule - Select Query" dialog as expected.  Once you have actually created a custom rule, and you go to create another one with List custom rules only checked, it also behaves as expected.

I cannot create custom rules if the "List custom rule only" option is not checked.

@Davon  I just tried it, same version of BHM and BizTalk 2020 (CU6), and it worked if I didn't check it.  Maybe download BHM again, and re-install it.

I already re-installed it and nothing change but I'm on BizTalk 2020 (CU5). Maybe there is an issue between BHM and CU5 ?

@Davon I didn't see anything in the contents for CU6 that is relevant to this issue.  But it won't hurt to upgrade at some point anyway.  If you are using BAM or EDI, make sure to read the notes on https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5048971-improvement-support-for-windows-server-2022-windows-11-and-sql-server-2022-in-biztalk-server-2020-b4e28aeb-f89b-44f1-809d-0da7535b8e89

I don't use BAM (I didn't installed it) maybe the issue come from there? Is BAM needed for BHM to works properly ? I didn't see anything regarding that but maybe I'm wrong.

@Davon No BAM is not needed for BHM.  I just put that note about BAM there regarding CU6.

Ok thank you. I will discuss with my PM about upgrading to CU6.
